# Symfony 3 group validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

It's doesnt't work as I expected.

Simple validation.yml

```
ForumBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    login:
        - NotIdenticalTo:
            value: ROOT
            message: Some Error
    phone:
        - NotBlank:
            message: Phone must be declared!
            groups: [admin]
    granted_by:
        - NotBlank:
            message: Your promotor must be declared!
            groups: [admin]
```

I would like to have 2 ways:

If user isn't admin just validate login property (works fine)

If user is admin validate all properties with `admin` group AND login property.

I tried to add code like that:

```
        $errors = $this
        ->get('validator')
        ->validate($user, null, array('admin'));
```

but when user is admin it just validate properties with admin group (login field is not validated). Is any solution without adding more groups?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the constraint for the `login` property is part of both the `Default` and the `admin` group:

```
ForumBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        login:
            - NotIdenticalTo:
                value: ROOT
                message: Some Error
                groups: [Default, admin]
        phone:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Phone must be declared!
                groups: [admin]
        granted_by:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Your promotor must be declared!
                groups: [admin]
```